Unable to Access Jito Labs Documentation
I’m setting up a Solana bot using the jito GitHub repository, https://github.com/jito-labs/mev-bot tools and need access to the documentation at https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/getting-started, but I get the error:
“You do not have access to this organization.”

How can I access this documentation or find an alternative way to get the resource? Any help is appreciated!

The repo mentions the docs are deprecated

